# Is it possible to encrypt screen flow text fields

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a screen flow that collects sensitive information about a customer. If a user is in debug logs or if it errors and an error email is sent, that sensitive information is included in error email. Is it possible to encrypt certain fields in a flow so that information is masked or does not get included in error emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon your comments, I don't really think this is a question of how to encrypt fields.

I think this is a question of how to control what information is available in emails. I know that you mention debug logs but as Mahmood said, only admins have access to that and admins can access that PII information anyway. I understand the issue with emails because those leave salesforce, go out into internet land where anyone with malicious intent can get access to those emails including secure and potentially identifiable information.

So, how do you make sure those emails do not contain that information? [Error Handling in Flows](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_build_logic_fault.htm&type=5). If you capture the error yourself instead of relying on what is sent automatically from salesforce, you can control the content and you simply leave out the information you dont want included. Mahmood does have a good point in that a lack of information can make things hard to troubleshoot but as we mentioned previously admins and devs can get the necessary information from debug logs which are much more secure then email. It may mean you have to turn on debug logs and go through reproducing the error which is not as convenient; however, security is inconvenient.

Comment: Thanks gNerb. I believe that's pretty much where I landed with this as well. I'm still relatively new to flows so just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing anything that would allow me to exclude or mask certain values based on the field type. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Error emails are sent to the last person who **updated** the flow, most likely an admin or developer. As mentioned in the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_troubleshoot_error_email.htm&type=5)

> When a process or flow interview fails, a detailed error email is sent
>   to the admin who last modified the process or flow.

You can change that behavior and send the error email to other admins using the process automation settings. Now, if you dont trust admin who has access to your entire org then you are stuck. By looking at the error email admin or developer would be able to debug / troubleshoot the issue. If you hide the information how do you expect them to resolve the issue?

If you think that the running user will get the email, he won't, unless you specify the user in the process automation settings.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm the user who receives the email as the admin. I'm more concerned with the content of the email for PCI compliance reasons. If there is PII data in there I wouldn't want it going to anyone in plaintext.